# ensure that utc datetime is persisted

Tags: c#, .net

Let us say I have a situation where I set the creation UTC date time just before I persist the entity. Usually, I would do it like this:

```
var something = new Something;
something.CreationDT = DateTime.UtcNow;
repo.Save(something);
```

What is the best way to ensure that this always happens. I know how to create a DateTime wrapper for testing purposes but this would not necessary help me here as programmers could still use:

```
something.CreationDT = DateTime.Now;
```

Is there a pattern to ensure that every programmer uses UTC?

Comment: Remove the (public) CreationDT setter, and set it to UtcNow in the constructor?

Comment: You could also let repo.Save take care of that, so you (or other developers) won't have to repeat the same line again and again.

Comment: Have you looked at DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime?

Comment: Hi Henk. What difference would that make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *always* want to force the UTC date on the object and this is the exact code, then just do it as part of the constructor e.g.

```
public Something()
{
    CreatedDT = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
public DateTime CreatedDT { get; private set; }
...
Save(new Something());
```

Obviously this doesn't cater for scenarios where you create the object earlier in the application and persist later, however, that doesn't appear to be the case here.

I would definitely avoid allowing users to set `Now` whilst internally returning `UtcNow`, that's just going to confuse people. If anything use `UtcNow` is *better* as it's more readable for the developer - it's clear to see that the value *has* to be UTC.

For this sort of thing, I generally try to let the DB do as much work as possible so I would have a default value set to the current UTC date/time so I don't need to worry about sending it from my client at all.

Comment: _the constructor_ is assuming a lot. Only a solution for single class apps.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I guess if all entities have CreationDT one could also set this in the repositories save method.

Comment: @csetzkorn yeah that's another alternative, however, I think the best approach would be to make the DB generate the date/time for you (if possible).